# Capturing camera stream in three.js on iOS

Tags: html, three.js, html5-video

I was woking on a project needing capture the camera video stream as a texture in three.js for the mobile phone. I was using the following code and it run fluently on Android but not on iPhones. The expectation is while user permitted to open the camera, the texture can hold the video stream and play what the camera captured. However, on iPhones, just displayed the first frame (it look likes) and then was left over a static view. Unless I called the video.play() function again then started playing the stream in a new fullscreen window. That was not I expected.

```
var constraints = { audio: false, video: true };

            navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
                .then(function (stream) {
                    console.log("success");
                    video.srcObject = stream;
                    video.play();
                })
                .catch(function(err) {
                    console.log('ERROR: ', err);
                });
            
            texture = new THREE.VideoTexture( video );
            texture.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
            texture.magFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
            texture.format = THREE.RGBFormat;

            material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { map: texture , side: THREE.DoubleSide} );
            mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry,  material);
            scene.add(mesh);
```

Is there any permissions I missed? Any way can work on iPhones?
Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 1):

Got Solution!

Seached from AR.js project, found and added the following code before getUserMedia, force "autoplay" and it worked.

```
video.setAttribute("autoplay", "");
video.setAttribute("muted", "");
video.setAttribute("playsinline", "");
```